# Как сделать, чтобы ComboBox открывался вверх, а не вниз?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как сделать, чтобы ComboBox открывался вверх, а не вниз?

Comment: Попробуйте поставить его на самый край формы.

Comment: На какой край он у меня расположен в самом низу и мне нужно задать открытие вверх когда нажимаешь на DropDownItem?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно отредактировать шаблон комбика и изменить параметры выпадающего элемента (Popup), чтобы он показывался сверху, а не снизу.

Answer (score 1):

Переопределить ControlTemplate для ComboBox и для Popup'а выставить Placement в Top.